# NHibernate - Duplicate Records with lazily mapped collection

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

All,

I have an entity, that has several collections,- each collection is mapped lazily. When I run a criteria query, I get duplicate results for my root entity in the result set. How's that possible when all my collections are mapped lazily!

I verified, my collections, load lazily.

Here's my mapping:

Root entity 'Project':

```
[Bag(0, Lazy = CollectionLazy.True, Inverse = true, Cascade = "all-delete-orphan")]
    [Key(1, Column = "job_id")]
    [OneToMany(2, ClassType = typeof(ProjectPlan))]
    public virtual IList<ProjectPlan> PlanList
    {
        get { return _planList; }
        set { _planList = value; }
    }
```

The criteria query is:

```
    ICriteria criteria = session.Session.CreateCriteria<Entities.Project>()
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq(Entities.Project.PROP_STATUS, !Entities.Project.STATUS_DELETED_FLAG));
                    .CreateAlias(Entities.Project.PROP_PLANLIST, "p")
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("p.County", 'MIDDLSEX'))
.setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(pageSize)
                    .List<Entities.Project>();
```

I know, I can correct this problem w/ Distinct result transformer, I just want to know if this is normal behavior on lazy collections.

EDIT: I found the cause of this,- when looking at the raw SQL, the join, and where clause are correct but what baffles me is the generated Select clause,- it not only contains columns from the project entity (root entity) but also columns from the project plans entity which causes the issue I described above. I am not at work right now, but I'll try to do this: .SetProjection(Projections.RootEntity()), so I only get Project's columns in the select clause.

Comment: I think I found carbon copy of my problem: http://floledermann.blogspot.ca/2007/10/solving-hibernate-criterias-distinct.html

Comment: Follow up to the above blog, looks like .setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(pageSize) are EVIL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, how to solve this *(I'd say so usual scenario)* is: 1) not use fetching collections inside of the query and 2) use batch fetching, as a part of the mapping

So, we will always be querying the root entity. That will give us a flat result set, which **can** be correctly used for **paging**.

To get the collection data for each recieved row, and to avoid 1 + N issue (goign for collection of each record) we will use [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)

The mapping would be like this

```
[Bag(0, Lazy = CollectionLazy.True
      , Inverse = true
      , Cascade = "all-delete-orphan"
      , BatchSize = 25)] // Or something similar to batch-size="25"
[Key(1, Column = "job_id")]
[OneToMany(2, ClassType = typeof(ProjectPlan))]
public virtual IList<ProjectPlan> PlanList
{
   ...
```

Some other similar QA *(with the almost same details)*

- [How to Eager Load Associations without duplication in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970680/)
- [NHibernate QueryOver with Fetch resulting multiple sql queries and db hits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284228/)
- [Is this the right way to eager load child collections in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199159/)

And we still can **filter** over the **collection items**! but we have to use subqueries, an example [Query on HasMany reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528760/)

Comment: I have to disagree w/ you,- the batch size only controls how many extra collections to pre-fetch when fetching current collection on given item. If you look at my mapping, I am using lazy loading,- w/out batch size it simply doesn't pre-fetch collections. If you also notice on the cirteria, I am fetching the root entity, .List<Project>(), which is the root entity,- I don't understand why it has other columns (other then root entity columns) in the select statement that don't get used when hydrating results.

Comment: The `.CreateAlias(Entities.Project.PROP_PLANLIST, "p")` is the answer. This is "the fetch" in fact this is the "JOIN", which makes your *root entity* selection multiplied by the amount of items in collections. What I am trying to explain you is: do not fetch (ie do not use `CreateAlias` `CreateCriteria` `SetFetchMode`). All of these will multiply the result. Instead change your mapping. Put **batch-size** on every collection mapping. At the end, you'll get the flat root entity in one SELECT and few more SQL select statements loading (lazy) collections. Is it more clear now? ;)

Comment: .CreateAlias(Entities.Project.PROP_PLANLIST, "p"), I thought, this should of altered only the from, where clauses, but I guess I am wrong. I thought, the batch-size only controlled the pre-fetching, but now your telling me that it also affects the select clause (I did not find that anywhere in hibernate docs)? I did NOT know that, I will definetly try this. Remember, my collections are already mapped lazy. I have other solutions to this like trying SetProjection(RootEntity()), or using subqueries w/ return Ids only that feed the main query on return a List of my root entities. Thanks for help.

Comment: Please, just a second: Let me clarify that: `CreateAlias`, `CreateCriteria`, `SetFetchMode` are ways how to extend the current SELECT **FROM** clause with more JOINed tables. But a **mapping attribute** `batch-size="25"` resp `BatchSize(25)` *in Fluent* is not effecting current SELECT clause at all. This setting *(the mapping with batch size)* is the way how to **optimize** the expost... lazy loading. Not to go for 1+N records but execute less 1+M statements ... in batches. Hope this helped ;) Good luck with NHibernate