# How to project the Collections in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-projections

Is it possible to project the collections in NHibernate?

For Example:

```cs
    User
    {
        UserGuid,
        IList<Groups> UserGroups,
    }
    
    User userEntity = null;

    _session
        .StatefulSession.QueryOver(() => userEntity)
        .SelectList(list => list
             .Select(x => x.UserGuid).WithAlias(() => userEntity.UserGuid)

             //How can I project group collection here?
             .Select(x => x.Groups).WithAlias(() => userEntity.Groups)
        )
        .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<UserEntity>())
        .List();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to thing about projection as a single SELECT clause. What we would be able to do with it on a DB side, we can mimic with `QueryOver`. So, in this case, we can join `User` and `Group`, and project few properties from User and few from Group. The best target would be some DTO...

The syntax could be like this:

```
ResultDTO resultDTO = null; // the target to be returned
Group groupEntity = null;
User userEntity = null;

_session.StatefulSession
    .QueryOver(() => userEntity)
    .JoinAlias(() => userEntity.Groups, () => groupEntity)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(x => x.UserGuid).WithAlias(() => resultDTO.UserGuid)
        // more about User - targeting the ResultDTO
        ...
        // almost the same for Group properties
        .Select(x => groupEntity.Name).WithAlias(() => resultDTO.GroupName)
        ..
    )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ResultDTO >())
    .List();
```

But there are some issues arround, which in fact effectively disallow this approach. We will reach the `Cartesian product`, because each row of a User will be multiplied as many times, as many Groups it does have.

```
Row 1 - User A - Group A
Row 2 - User A - Group B // two rows for a user A
Row 3 - User B - Group B
Row 4 - User B - Group C
```

One way to solve it, is to skip the `SelectList()` *(do not use projections)* and ask NHiberante to use different transformation:

```
_session.StatefulSession
    .QueryOver(() => userEntity)
    .JoinAlias(() => userEntity.Groups, () => groupEntity)
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
    .List();
```

Nice, one would say, but it is wrong again. No effective paging is possible, because the effect of more rows for each User still remains. So, if we would say `Take(2)`, we will get only *User A*. The reason is hidden in fact, that the narrowing is done expost, in memory, on .NET/Application tier side - not in DB

Suggestion: Do not use any joins among one-to-many relations. Use the separated queries with conjunction of powerful NHibernate feature: [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)

Please, see also:

- [NHibernate QueryOver with Fetch resulting multiple sql queries and db hits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284228/)
- [Is this the right way to eager load child collections in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199159/)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419988/