# Use NHibernate AliasToBean Transformer launch n+1 query

Tags: nhibernate

Before edit my question I'm sorry for my poor english.

I have two classes:

```
public class News
{
    public virtua int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Content { get; set; }                
    public virtual LearningCenter LearningCenter { get; set; }
}

public class LearningCenter
{
    public virtua int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string Mail { get; set; }
    public virtual string DDECode { get; set; }
}
```

I get a list of news using a main code like:

```
var query = Session
                .QueryOver<News>()
                .JoinAlias(x => x.Language, () => language, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                .JoinAlias(x => x.LearningCenter, () => learningCenter, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                .List<News>();
```

The code above is translated from NHibernate to a single sql query that looks something like "SELECT ... FROM News LEFT JOIN LearningCenter WHERE ..."

It's working fine. But I want to select a group of fields, so I make something like... (Note news and newsDTO object has same type)

```
News news = null;
LearningCenter learningCenter = null;
Language language = null;
News newsDTO = null;

var query = Session
                .QueryOver(() => news)
                .JoinAlias(() => news.LearningCenter, () => learningCenter, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                .JoinAlias(() => news.Language, () => language, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                .SelectList(l => l
                .Select(x => x.Id).WithAlias(() => newsDTO.Id)
                .Select(x => x.LearningCenter).WithAlias(() => newsDTO.LearningCenter))
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<News>())
                .List<News>();
```

But the issue is NHibernate translate the code above to n+1 query that looks something like...

"SELECT ... FROM News LEFT JOIN LearningCenter WHERE..."
"SELECT ... FROM LearningCenter WHERE CenterId = 388"
"SELECT ... FROM LearningCenter WHERE CenterId = 389"
...

Do you know how can I make for NHibernate translate the code to a single query?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there are two ways.

1) we have to use Projections, and project all properties to be selected explicitly. Then we have to use some deeper transformation e.g. [Deep transformer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24248309/1679310)

2) we can use batch fetching, which will load all related relations in few batches. That will lead to 1 + 2(4) queries, to load all relations in separated (few) queries

For more details about projections:

- [How to partially project a child object with many fields in nHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26893475/1679310)

For more details about batch fetching you can check this:

- documentation - http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch
- [How to Eager Load Associations without duplication in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20970680/1679310) or
- [NHibernate: Select one to Many Left Join - Take X latest from Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27692331/1679310)