# NHibernate select a list of objects with related child objects with QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I'm having trouble with something that is probably very simple.
In my database I have the following tables:

```
tblOrder
-----------------
Id
OrderStatusId

tblOrderStatus
-----------------
Id
Name
```

And I have made the following mappings in my project:

```
[Class(NameType = typeof(Order), Table = "tblOrder")
public class Order {
    [Id(-2, Name = "Id")]
    [Generator(-1, Class = "native")]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public virtual OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
}

[Class(NameType = typeof(OrderStatus), Table = "tblOrderStatus")]
public class OrderStatus {
    [Id(-2, Name = "Id")]
    [Generator(-1, Class = "native")]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The query should return a `IList<OrderSummary>`. I want the class `OrderSummary` to have a property `Status` where `Status` is an object with an `Id` and a `Name` property. This could be either with a `KeyValuePair` or of type `OrderStatus` (whichever is best and works). Fetching the orders is not a problem but adding the `OrderStatus` as an object with said properties is the part I'm having trouble with.
I also need to return the result of the query as JSON to the client.

`OrderSummary` should look like this:

```
public class OrderSummary {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

In my first version `OrderSummary` had separate properties for `OrderStatusId` and `OrderStatusName`. This works but I'm trying to avoid these separate properties. 
I have also tried this with `SelectSubQuery` but this returns an error because it returns more than one field in a subquery.

----------------------------------- UPDATE -----------------------------

Following Fredy Treboux's advice I changed my query using `Eager` which result in the following query:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<OrderStatus>
    .Fetch(o => o.Status).Eager
    .JoinAlias(o => o.Status, () => statusAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
```

The problem is, I found out, is not selecting the data but how to convert the retrieved `Status` and assign it to OrderSummary.Status? I have tried the following:

```
OrderSummary orderAlias = null;
query.SelectList(list => list
    .Select(o => o.Id).WithAlias(() => orderAlias.Id)
    .Select(() => statusAlias).WithAlias(() => orderAlias.Status)
).TransformUsing(Transformer.AliasToBean<OrderSummary>());
```

-------------------------------- ANSWER ----------------------------------

As I said in my last edit, the problem does not seem to be the actual selection of `OrderStatus` but returning it to the client. So I thought it was my lack of knowledge of NHibernate instead it was as simple as adding the `[JsonObject]` attribute to the `OrderStatus` class. How silly of me.

I have changed my query to the following:

```
Order orderAlias = null;
OrderSummary orderSummary = null;
OrderStatus statusAlias = null;
var query = session.QueryOver<Order>(() => orderAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => orderAlias.Status, () => statusAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);

query = query
    .Select(
        Projections.ProjectionList()
            .Add(Projections.Property(() => orderAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => orderSummary.Id))
            .Add(Projections.Property(() => orderAlias.Status).WithAlias(() => orderSummary.Status)
    );
Result = query.TransformUsing(Tranformers.AliasToBean<OrderSummary>())
    .List<OrderSummary>()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644236/use-nhibernate-aliastobean-transformer-launch-n1-query

Comment: I have looked over the links you posted there have used the solution that is put into a comment there:
`var query = session.QueryOver<Order>()
        .SelectList(list => 
             .Select(Projections.Property("OrderStatus").As("OrderStatus"))
        );`

The result seems ok, but the json the is sent to the client the order does contain an OrderStatus property but the property contains metadata only and not the actual values of the properties.

Comment: Do you mean proxies? In this case try to disable lazyloading for Status property

Comment: Can I ask why are you trying to accomplish it like this instead of just querying the orders (eager fetching the statuses) and building your OrderSummary DTO by code (instead of trying to get NHibernate to map to it for you)? If I'm not missing something that seems like a much simpler option (let me know if you would like an example).

Comment: It's purely lack of knowledge. Could you give me an example of how to do that?

Comment: did you explore a custom type (IUserType) ? see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242022/nhibernate-mapping-to-custom-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I didn't see your comment asking for an example before.
I'm going to leave some code explaining the approach I mentioned, although it was already given as an alternative in the other response and I believe it's the easiest way to go (not using transformers at all):

```
string GetOrderSummaries()
{
   // First, you just query the orders and eager fetch the status.
   // The eager fetch is just to avoid a Select N+1 when traversing the returned list.
   // With that, we make sure we will execute only one query (it will be a join).
   var query = session.QueryOver<Order>()
                      .Fetch(o => o.Status).Eager;

   // This executes your query and creates a list of orders.
   var orders = query.List();

   // We map these orders to DTOs, here I'm doing it manually.
   // Ideally, have one DTO for Order (OrderSummary) and one for OrderStatus (OrderSummaryStatus).
   // As mentioned by the other commenter, you can use (for example) AutoMapper to take care of this for you:
   var orderSummaries = orders.Select(order => new OrderSummary
   {
      Id = order.Id,
      Status = new OrderSummaryStatus
      {
         Id = order.Status.Id,
         Name = order.Status.Name
      }
   }).ToList();

   // Yes, it is true that this implied that we not only materialized the entities, but then went over the list a second time.
   // In most cases I bet this performance implication is negligible (I imagine serializing to Json will possibly be slower than that).
   // And code is more terse and possibly more resilient.

   // We serialize the DTOs to Json with, for example, Json.NET
   var orderSummariesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(orderSummaries);
   return orderSummariesJson;
 }
```

**Useful links:**
AutoMapper: http://automapper.org/
Json.NET: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that currently it's not possible. I guess that Nhibernate transformers are not able to construct nested complex properties. 
You can return list of tuples and then cast it manually to your entity:

```
OrderStatus statusAlias = null;        

var tuples = Session.QueryOver<Order>()
            .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Status, () => statusAlias)
            .SelectList(list => list
                .Select(x => x.Id)
                .Select(x => statusAlias.Id)
                .Select(x => statusAlias.Name))
            .List<object[]>();

var result = tuples.Select(Convert);

private OrderSummary Convert(object[] item) {
            return new OrderSummary
            {
                Id = (long)item[0],
                OrderStatus = new OrderStatus { Id = (long)item[1], Name = (string)item[2] }
            };
        }
```

Also if you don't bother about performance much it's possible to fetch a list of you Orders and convert it to OrderSummary. You can do it by simply define casting operator or using some tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or [ExpressMapper](http://www.expressmapper.org/).