# NHibernate. QueryOver Take(n) - with Left.Join

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

Got some strange behaviour when using `Take()` with join. Suppose the following example:

```
Comment comment = null;
var persons = _repository
        .QueryOver()
        .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Comments, () => comment)
        .Where(x => x.Age > 20)
        .Take(5)
        .Future()
        .ToList();
```

Well I'd expect that `5` persons are present in the array, and each of them has a list of `N comments`.

But, the result givest `5` persons, with a maximum of `5` comments.

**Why is `.Take(5)` also restricting the number of comments?**

How to achieve the desired result?

Comment: This is a classic cartesian product problem. NH doesn't page the root BUT the root + children. Like Radim has answered fetch parents with paging and lazy load with batching the children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point here is a difference in our need of paging and its implementation.

- while we would expect 5 **root** elements to be returned,
- the result is converted into 5 *rows*, 5 selected rows :

Some clue could be found in this Q & A: [NHibernate QueryOver with Fetch resulting multiple sql queries and db hits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19284228/1679310)

In case of paging with [SQL Server 2012 dialect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13220743/1679310), we would see SQL like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM root
JOIN collection
WHERE....
OFFSET 0 ROWS -- skip 0 or 10 or 20 rows
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY; -- take 5 rows
```

So it could at the end result in returning just ONE root entity, if amount of chidren (comments) is 5+

Solution? I would suggest to do it by:

- select just **root** entity
- use batch fetching to load children

Selecting just root, could eve mean select also any many-to-one/Reference. This will end up in a star schema structure, which with left joins will again correctly page over the root entity.

Batch fetching is described here in doc:

#### [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)

Some similar issues:

- [NHibernate: Select one to Many Left Join - Take X latest from Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27692331/1679310)
- [How to Eager Load Associations without duplication in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20970680/1679310)

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. Appreciate your help++

Comment: Great to see that, sir! Enjoy awesome NHibernate ;)